# Sort function that uses an integer array argument doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I'm a beginner trying to learn JS, I've got some basic knowledge.
I wrote a function to realize insertion sort on a given array (the array is passed on to the function as a parameter).

When I initialize the array and give it value, e.g, 
    sampleArray = [1,35,73,234,1,1,356];
and pass that to my function, it works perfectly.
however, if I try to pass on an array filled by user input - or an array that was merged out of two given arrays (my original assignment),
it doesn't work - no exceptions or errors, it just... doesn't sort as expected.

I've been racking my mind over this, maybe I don't know where to look?

```
function sortArray(arrT) {
    for (let i = 1; i < arrT.length; i++){
        var tempMax = arrT[i];
        var j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (arrT[j] > tempMax)) {
            console.log(arr1 + "\nj=" + j + " i=" + i);
            arrT[j+1] = arrT[j];
            j--;
        }
        arrT[j+1] = tempMax;
    }
    console.log("sorted array is (inside loop) :\n" +arrT);
    return arrT;
}
```

for an array that was filled by a while loop of prompts such as
it's equal to the above sample array, the result is
1,1,1,234,35,356,73

for reference, though it's far from elegant, I'm using this to fill the array:

```
for (let i = 0, x = ""; x !== "x"; i++) {
    x = prompt("press x to finish, enter to continue");
    if (x == "x") { break }
    arr1[i]=prompt("enter");
}
```

Comment: Welcome DSF! Can you please add a sample of an "array filled with user input"?

Comment: Are you sure the array is an **array of integers**? perhaps you are receiving an **array of strings** instead, like ['1','1','234','35']... Besides, just to add something to the boilerplate, there already is a **sort** method on arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort which also happens to work in-place.

Comment: Try using `parseInt()` when comparing the inputs. You  might see an error if any of the imputs is not a valid number

Comment: @briosheje thanks, I'll try - can it pass the array as an array of strings even though I put in integers? as for the built-in sort method, I know it exists, however, I'm studying so that I can get into formal studies and I need to sort it without methods, as much as I can :)

Comment: @StefanN I added the loop I used, and the "user filled" one has me filling the same values as the sample array, thru that loop, then passing it to the func

Comment: @DSF if you are proving the array, no. Otherwise, if the array is coming from some sort of merging or other sources, it can do that, meaning that an unknown source can be anything, even something which is **not** an array. Perhaps you should first check whether each element is numeric: if it's not, try make it a number; if it's NaN, throw an error ;)

Comment: Why you are using prompts two times? while the task is achievable in one prompt. replace arr1[i] = x;

Comment: @brioshje the problem is I AM providing the array - at least in this scenario. I'll add checks for numbers and NaN, see if that sorts it out :)

Comment: @sagar thanks, I didn't think about it. Like I said - my code is (for now!) Far from elegant :)

Comment: @DSF prompt actually returns **strings**. You should **cast that to a number before proceding**.

Comment: @DSF you should select the answer below if you find it helpful. Moreover using parseInt may help you in some other undesirable situations. However, JS will handle the correctly inserted number values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0, x = ""; x !== "x"; i++) {
    x = prompt("press x to finish, enter to continue");
    if (x == "x") { break }
    arr1[i]=prompt("enter");
}
```

`prompt` actually returns a string, hence your input is **an array of strings instead**. You should use `Number` to ensure the provided value is numeric.

I would rewrite the above in this way:

```js
// stores all the values.
var arr1 = [];

// Stores the current value.
var input;
do {
  var _ = prompt("press x to finish, enter to continue"); // <-- not sure why you're doing that every time, I would suggest you to move it outside of the loop.
  input = prompt("enter");
  var n = Number(input);
  if (!isNaN(n)) arr1.push(n); // <-- checks whether the provided value is actually numeric and a valid number. If it is, the value is added to the collection.
}
while (input !== 'x');

console.log(arr1);
```

I would suggest you to move the first prompt outside of the loop, but since you did it in your code, I suspect there is a reason for that, though I don't get it.

In any case, the above sample will check whether the value passed is valid; if it is, it push the item to the collection, otherwise it continues until 'x' is met.

Comment: this would not work under some circumstances. For example: Input is "iota", "888", "99" ....

Comment: @sagar The input is supposed to acquire **numbers**. If the value passed is not numeric, it should be handled in the loop itself. OP is trying to **acquire an array of integers**, hence the only feasible solution against prompt is to actually try to convert the string value to a numeric one. If, for some reasons, it is not a numeric value, it should not add the value and handle the case, it's out of question to handle every single possible input, but definitely fair to handle any number. Other solutions would require a regex and that would make sense in other scenarios, but not here.

Comment: there is not requirement of isNaN as Number() in itself return NaN if it is not a number. So there is no requirement of using isNaN(). Moreover, it would perform typecasting if you use it in non-constructor context. You should take a reference "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number"

Comment: @sagar you must use `isNaN` to check whether a numeric value is NaN (since you can't compare against NaN). The check would still require two calls, unless I'm wrong, which I might be, of course ;). Your lovely downvote makes it interesting, though, since the proposed solution actually works and definitely can be improved, but **works** ;)

Comment: However, global isNaN is not recommended because it passes some undesirable values like undefined. The best possible case is Number.isNaN() "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN"

Comment: @sagar _global isNaN is not recommended because it passes some undesirable values like undefined_ I think we're going on some personal thoughs against someone's answer. Unless there is relevant proof that global isNaN should be avoided, I'm not going any further. I don't feel you're trying to increase the value of my answer, but you're rather trying to give destructive feedback, which is not what I'm looking for. Due to the usage of isNaN here, which is used against an if condition, either `false`, `null` or `undefined` will all act as falsy values, hence any eventual problem should not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding. 
The mistake is here

Original Code:

```
for (let i = 0, x = ""; x !== "x"; i++) {
    x = prompt("press x to finish, enter to continue"); 
    if (x == "x") { break }
    arr1[i]=prompt("enter");//do not use prompts while unnecessary. Just replace it with x;
}
```

Corrected One:

```
for (let i = 0, x = ""; x !== "x"; i++) {
    x = prompt("press x to finish, enter to continue"); 
    if (x == "x") { break }
    /*
    you can also improve your code by applying few checks
    if(!isNaN(x)) continue; // --- to skip when input value isn't a number
    */

    arr1[i]=x;
}
```